# How to make a search button action event?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextfield, jlist

The GUI has a search bar that when the user types a book and click search, it pops up on the `JList`. But I don't know how to write the code for it.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   if (e.getSource() == searchButton) {
       // Action for the SEARCH button
```

Comment: would it be like  bookListModel.getElement(String);

Answer (score 1):

Keep the original unfiltered data in a structure (e.g an ArrayList) and add a `DocumentListener` to the search textfield in order to know whether the search text has been changed. Then, filter the original data and `removeAllElements()` from `JList`'s model. Finally add the the filtered data to the model of `JList`.

Example:

```
public class SearchInJList extends JFrame implements DocumentListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1662279563193298340L;
    private JList<String> list;
    private List<String> data;
    private DefaultListModel<String> model;
    private JTextField searchField;

    public SearchInJList() {
        super("test");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        searchField = new JTextField();
        searchField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(this);
        add(searchField, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        createData();

        list = new JList<>(model = new DefaultListModel<>());
        data.forEach(model::addElement);
        add(new JScrollPane(list), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setSize(500, 500);
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
    }

    private void createData() {
        data = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            String s = "String: " + i + ".";
            data.add(s);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            SearchInJList example = new SearchInJList();
            example.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        search();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        search();
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        search();
    }

    private void search() {
        List<String> filtered = data.stream().filter(s -> s.toLowerCase().contains(searchField.getText().toLowerCase()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        model.removeAllElements();
        filtered.forEach(model::addElement);
    }
}
```

It does not work with a button, but I guess this is something you can do. I mean add the `search()` method into button's action listener.

Comment: *"It does not work with a button, but.."* But nothing! Searching on typing is the better solution for 99%(1) of situations. 1) I wrote a similar thing for the Unicode charset with over a million entries. It was so many entries it was necessary to make a `SwingWorker` for it. But it did not make much sense to create the worker for every event, so the code started a timer to schedule it. (Or .. a more complicated implementation of what you did.) I **could** have gotten around the problem by adding an action listener instead. Search being done one when the user presses 'enter' in text field ..

Comment: .. but that **still** would not have required a button as the OP was originally using!

Answer (score 0):

So for every button press you can:

1. Fill a [`DefaultListModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html) with the strings that match the search criteria.
2. Create a new [`JList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) with the model of the previous step.
3. Pop a [`JOptionPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) with the list of the previous step as its message.

Example code:

```
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        final String[] data = new String[]{"abcdef", "ABCdEF", "defGhi", "DEFghi"};

        final JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);

        final JButton searchButton = new JButton("Search");
        searchButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            final String searchText = textField.getText().toLowerCase();
            final DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
            for (final String str: data)
                if (str.toLowerCase().contains(searchText))
                    model.addElement(str);
            final JList<String> list = new JList<>(model);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(searchButton, list);
        });

        final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(textField);
        panel.add(searchButton);

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Search form");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```